# Using same methods in two models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am customising slug method for auto generating and i am using like this

**models.py**

```
 class Category(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Category.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
        num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am using this **_get_unique_slug** method in another model. But I wander if there is beautiful way to right this in mixins. I mean without writing get_unique_slug for each model. How do I this? Thank you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write this as a mixin and reference `self.__class__`.

```
class UniqueSlugMixin:
    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while self.__class__.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug
```

Comment: then shall I this method inherit? class Category(TimeStamp, UniqueSlugMixin): like this?

Comment: I am created a new file named mixin.py but there is unrecognized stuff. they are name and objects can you tell me how i can solve this?